# Error with new R 3.1.3 version

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed the new `R 3.1.3`. I now get the error at start up:

```
Error in .rs.httpdPort() : attempt to apply non-function
```

Help does not work. In example:

```
?get
```

redirects to my browser.

Any ideas what one could do about it?

I use `"7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1"`, Windows x86-64

Best Regards

Comment: Do you have a custom Rprofile.site file?

Comment: @Roland the error appeared before I added my custom Rprofile.site and also after I did add it.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you use RStudio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202522708-Error-in-rs-httpdPort-

Comment: @Roland yes...Thats true.

Comment: Same issue on my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit machine. Upgrading to the newest version of RStudio (version 0.98.1103, based on the solution suggested by @Molx) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update to RStudio version 0.98.110**3**, it's available (even if it says in RStudio's updater that there's not a newer version available).

*Edit a few months later*

Though RStudio has been updated a few times since this question was first asked, the idea remains the same for those with this problem: Update RStudio to its latest version, and remember to check [the website](https://www.rstudio.com/) because the auto-updater may not work.

Comment: OK, now we just need to figure out how to update to RStudio version 0.98.1103....

Comment: Download the installer from [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) or use the function `install.RStudio()` from the `installr` package.

Comment: Had the same problem with one of 0.99.XX version (as I updated it and it worked, I didn't quite pay attention which one was it).

Comment: InstallR is not available for R versions below at least 3.4.1. I didn't try below that.