# "Error in (function () : attempt to apply non-function" when using the help-function

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R studio 0.98.110 on Windows. I recently updated to R 3.1.3. All works fine except this weird thing: whenever I try to get help from the console I get 4 times the error `Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function` and the help is displayed in my explorer (Firefox) instead of the Help panel of RStudio. If I look for help from the search bar of the panel it is correctly displayed there.

Example:

```
> ?help
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you update `RStudio`?

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't work.

Comment: uninstall both R and Rstudio then reinstall R then reinstall Rstudio with the lastest versions of each.

Comment: Do you have an `Rprofile` file somewhere? maybe it's doing something.

Comment: I checked my Rprofile, but all normal and `chaning options(help_type=)` didn't solved it. As said before, updating to Version 0.98.1102 didn't work but now that 0.99.467 is available the error is gone. Seems I had a similar problem than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967242/error-with-new-r-3-1-3-version